# Kubernetes Node Memory Limits

Tags: kubernetes

I'm a beginner on Kubernetes. When I described my node, I saw this at the very bottom:

```
kubectl describe node ip-x-x-x-x.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal 

...

Allocated resources:
(Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
CPU Requests  CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits
------------  ----------  ---------------  -------------
225m (11%)    200m (10%)  125Mi (1%)       300Mi (3%)
Events:         <none>
```

How do I un-limit the memory + cpu?

Comment: easy. Don't set a limit for what you deploy!

Comment: also this question has been answered plenty of times, a simple google search would have done: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/

Comment: @iomv This is wen I describe node, not my pod: `kubectl describe node blah-blah-blah`

Comment: @iomv also, I don't define any limits. My namespace doesn't have any default limits as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every node has limits according to its resources: number of processors or cores, amount of memory. Kubernetes uses this information for distributing Pods across Nodes.

Referring to the official documentation:

**- Meaning of CPU**
One CPU, in Kubernetes, is equivalent to:
- 1 AWS vCPU
- 1 GCP Core
- 1 Azure vCore
- 1 Hyperthread on a bare-metal Intel processor with Hyperthreading
1 CPU is 1000m (1 thousand milicores)

**- Meaning of memory**. It is an amount of memory on the server.

In the output from `kubectl describe node <node-name>` command, you see statistics of resource usage. Actually, resources of your server can be counted from the example in question, it is 2 CPUs/Cores and around 10000 MB of memory.

Please note that some resources are already allocated by system Pods like kube-dns, kube-proxy or kubernetes-dashboard.