# Kubernetes Node Details

Tags: kubernetes

[Image for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U450c.png)

I have 2 questions:

1. I have a node on kubernetes cluster, I wanted to know the difference between CPU request, limit on this image. **I know the difference between limit,request on deployment file** but this seems something different
2. In image there's pod allocation capacity ( So far I know this is the limit of running pods at a specific moment ). I wanted to know if pending pods are also included in this capacity or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values are the total of the values for the 4 pods on the node, shown as a fraction of the total resource available on the node. So e.g. you could have a maximum of 110 pods on the node and you currently have 4. You can use this to get a sense of when your node is nearing being 'full' (i.e. if one of those metrics is almost full then it's likely that kubernetes [won't be able to schedule](http://www.noqcks.io/notes/2018/02/03/understanding-kubernetes-resources/) any more pods to that node). It's the [same metrics you get from `kubectl describe node <node_name>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50912066/kubernetes-node-memory-limits)

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't answers my question.

Comment: Sorry I missed parts of your question. As I understand it pending pods are not included as they are not yet scheduled to any particular node. Is there any further point that the answer didn't address?

Comment: It would be good to try to improve the answer and make it as clear as possible.

Comment: ok thanks for the pending part...
and yes,, I asked asked the limit, request thing.. I know if i specify a limit in a YAML file and that pod goes beyond that limit then it's terminated. What I don't understand is the limit,request thing on a NODE.

Comment: There are no resource limits that you set for nodes (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/50369#issuecomment-321817042). But there are hard resource constraints for a node as it is a machine virtual machine instance so it can run out of memory or cpu if too many pods are scheduled to it or the pods are too demanding for it. Kubernetes uses the request and limit on pods to schedule them to nodes in a way that protects the nodes against being overwhelmed. That's why the metrics shown for a node are the totals of the metrics for the pods on the node.

Comment: So the limit value for cpu on the node represents how much cpu the pods on the node would be using if they were all running at their maximum (I.e. all pods using their full limit). The request cpu for the node represents how much cpu the pods on the node would use if all running at exactly their requested cpu amount. The book Mastering Kubernetes by Gigi Sayfan has a good explanation.

Comment: It helps me to think of Kubernetes scheduling pods to multiple nodes and some nodes in the cluster being more powerful than others. Then Kubernetes needs to keep a balance to best use the nodes available. If there's only one node (e.g. Minikube) then scheduling options are very limited.